# Template of IEEE Signal Processing Letters

Tags: ieeetran

I am searching for the TeX template of the IEEE Signal Processing Letters.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: There should be a link in the Journal's web-page under the "Information for Authors" or in IEEE Author Tools. All IEEE Transactions journals use the same template, except for the IEEE Transactions on Magnetics, IEEE Transactions on Dielectrics and Electrical Insulation.

Comment: Or visit https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran?lang=en and read the documentation PDF.